# How to download a file from URL without showing the full path in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Download link:-

```
 <a  href='"+ downloadlink + '/attachment-download/' + $('#employee_ID').val()+'/'+ res[i].file_name +"'>
```

Route:-

```
Route::get('/attachment-download/{id}/{filename}', array(
 'uses' => 'AttachmentsController@getDownloadAttachments'
));
```

Attachment Controller:-

```
public function getDownloadAttachments($id,$filename){
    $file="./img/user-icon.png";

    $resource = \Employee::WhereCompany()->findOrfail($id);

    $path = $this->attachmentsList($resource);

    foreach($path as $index => $attachment){
        if ($filename == $attachment['file_name']) {
        $filePath = $attachment['url'];
        }
    }
    //return \Response::download($file);
    return \Response::download($filePath);
}


File URL Output:-
https://zetpayroll.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/employees/81/Screenshot%20from%202017-04-26%2015%3A07%3A45.png?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI57OFN3HPCBPQZIQ%2F20170612%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170612T144818Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=59ecc4d11b7ed71bd336531bd7f4ab7c84da6b7424878d6487679c97a8c52ca7
```

In this, if try to download the file by using a static path like

```
 $file="./img/user-icon.png";  
 return \Response::download($file);
```

it is downloaded fine. But not possible to downloading file from AWS URL, Please help me how to down file automatically using URL. Or How to get Path from URL in laravel or PHP.
Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that your AWS url is correct?

Comment: Yes. While run that path in browser file downloaded . But i changed path in question "/zetpayroll.s3.ap-south-1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the above function all the files are being downloaded. But while trying to open the files, text, pdf, ... files open (`.text, .csv, .pdf..`) without problem, but images don't.

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);

$response = response($fileContent, 200, [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
   'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"',
]);

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another solution for download file from URL

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
                echo file_get_contents('https://www.pakainfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/image-url-for-testing.jpg');
            }, 'image-url-for-testing.jpg');
```

You can use stream download. here it is reference : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#streamed-downloads

Comment: In-case of large file set memory limit in your code as i get the large file issue.